# How do I fix this ts-toolbelt TypeScript TypeError on Vercel deployment for a Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

In my portfolio app, I'm trying to merge a PR into the main branch, which contains code to implement React Query. The app works fine on development but when I try to deploy it, Vercel gives me the error above that apparently occurs when they try to build my app.

I tried installing ts-toolbelt as a dependency but it doesn't seem to work.

[Here's the project's repo and precisely to the failing PR](https://github.com/juanzitelli/juanzitelli-dev/pull/2) (You wont' get access to the vercel deployment details as it's my account, but every error that appears is shown in the picture above)

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running `npm run build` locally?

Comment: Yep! @juliomalves here's the output, it's the same as vercel's ==> [terminal's screen shot](https://postimg.cc/qtXdqnFN)

Comment: PD: @juliomalves I already ran the NPX command suggested above the error, and that message keeps on appearing...

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me and after some research looks like the ts-toolbar version that comes in the React-Query package is not compatible with the Typescript version my React app is using.

To fix it I added a `resolutions` field on the `package.json` to force the ts-toolbelt dependency to a compatible version, like so:

```
"resolutions": {
   "ts-toolbelt": "6.15.5"
}
```

`6.15.5` being the ts-toolbelt version compatible with my Typescript version (`3.8.3`)

Then running `yarn install` solved the issue for me.